# Is a specific endomorphism of $A_1$ an automorphism?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-rings

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero, and let $A_1(k)$ be the first Weyl algebra, namely, the associative non-commutative $k$-algebra generated by $x$ and $y$ subject to the relation $yx-xy=1$.

Suppose that the following map $f$ is a $k$-algebra endomorphism of $A_1$:
$(x,y) \mapsto (f(x):=p,f(y):=q)$,
where $p=uy$ and $q=x+vy$, $u,v \in A_1(k)$, $y$ does not divide $u$,
namely, $u \notin A_1y$.

As a $k$-algebra endomorphism of $A_1(k)$, we have $[q,p]=1$; indeed, just apply $f$ to $yx-xy=1$.

> Is it true that $f$ is actually an automorphism of $A_1(k)$?
>   In particular, is it true that necessarily $p=- y$?

**My partial answer:**
$1=[q,p]=[x+vy,uy]=[x,uy]+[vy,uy]=-[uy,x]+[vy, uy]$
$=-(u[y,x]+[u,x]y)+[vy,uy]=-(u+[u,x]y)+[vy,uy]=-u-[u,x]y+[vy,uy]$

Denote: $E:=[vy,uy]$. Then,
$E=[vy,uy]=v[y,uy]+[v,uy]y=-v[uy,y]-[uy,v]y=$
$-v(u[y,y]+[u,y]y)-[uy,v]y=-v[u,y]y-[uy,v]y=$
$-v[u,y]y-(u[y,v]y+[u,v]y^2)=$
$-v[u,y]y-u[y,v]y-[u,v]y^2$.

So we have $E=-v[u,y]y-u[y,v]y-[u,v]y^2$.
Then, $1=-u-[u,x]y-v[u,y]y-u[y,v]y-[u,v]y^2$.

Write $u=a_ny^n+\cdots+a_1y+a_0$, $a_j \in k[x]$, $a_0 \neq 0$ (since we have assumed that $y$ does not divide $u$).
We see that $a_0=-1$.

Now, the highest $(0,1)$-term of $-u-[u,x]y-v[u,y]y-u[y,v]y-[u,v]y^2$ should be zero, and by considerations of $(0,1)$-degrees, it equals the $(0,1)$-highest term of  $-[u,v]y^2$.

---

**Motivation:** Please see [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/334897/a-non-commutative-analog-of-a-result-concerning-a-jacobian-pair) question, in order to understand the motivation for my above question.

Any hints and comments are welcome!
(I have also asked the above question in [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3281015/is-a-specific-endomorphism-of-a-1-an-automorphism), but have not received any comments yet).

Comment: If $B=0$ and $A=x$ then $y$ does not divide $A$, but relations are not preserved

Comment: @MarcoFarinati, thank you for your comment (but $[q,p] \neq 1$, as you mentioned).

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand your question properly. Do you begin with an endomorphism $f$ or you begin with $A$ and $B$ and try to define $f$? You probable know that $f$ Endo implies $f$ auto is an old conjecture

Comment: @MarcoFarinati, thanks. I begin with a specific $f: (x,y) \mapsto (Ay,x+By)$. Yes, I am familiar with the Dixmier Conjecture. My above question is about a special case.

Comment: did you try the Z-grading $|x|=1$ and $|y|=-1$, introducing $h=yx$,  and writing $A$ and $B$ in terms of polynomials on $h$ and powers of $x$ + polynomial on $h$ times powers of $y$? Bavula had a lot of success using this grading

Comment: Thank you for your advice. (I have tried considering the $(1,-1)$-degrees. Perhaps I should try more).

Comment: @user237522 Thanks for mentioning you asked the question also in MSE, but I suggest in the future you also include the link, e.g., as in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3281015/is-a-specific-endomorphism-of-a-1-an-automorphism), to make it easier for anybody else to check on it. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnOmielan, thank you for your comment. You are right. I will add the link.

Comment: $A$ is not a good notation for an element of a ring $A_1$... does "$y$ does not divide $A$" mean $A\notin A_1y$? "divide" is somewhat ambiguous in a noncommutative ring.

Comment: @YCor, thank you for your comment. ok, I will change the notation. Indeed, "$y$ does not divide $A$" means $A \notin A_1y$.